# Calculate the partial derivative $\frac{\partial^{n+m}{f}}{\partial{x}^n\partial{y}^m}$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $$f( x, y) = \frac{1}{(1 − x^2)( y − y^2)}$$ and $n$, $m$ be non-negative integers. Calculate the partial derivative

$$\frac{\partial^{n+m}{f}}{\partial{x}^n\partial{y}^m}$$

I calculated the $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$, $\frac{\partial^{2}{f}}{\partial{x}^2}$, $\frac{\partial^{3}{f}}{\partial{x}^3}$, $\frac{\partial^{4}{f}}{\partial{x}^4}$ and $\frac{\partial^{5}{f}}{\partial{x}^5}$. I see some part of the final form already, but not the whole picture, some parts still confuse me. Also I wanted to see if there is any trivial method for computing $n$th order partial derivatives.

$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} = -\dfrac{2x}{\left(y-1\right)y\left(x^2-1\right)^2}$

$\frac{\partial^{2}{f}}{\partial{x}^2} = \dfrac{2\left(3x^2+1\right)}{\left(y-1\right)y\left(x^2-1\right)^3}$

$\frac{\partial^{3}{f}}{\partial{x}^3} = -\dfrac{24x\left(x^2+1\right)}{\left(y-1\right)y\left(x^2-1\right)^4}$

$\frac{\partial^{4}{f}}{\partial{x}^4} = \dfrac{24\left(5x^4+10x^2+1\right)}{\left(y-1\right)y\left(x^2-1\right)^5}$

$\frac{\partial^{5}{f}}{\partial{x}^5} = -\dfrac{240x\left(3x^4+10x^2+3\right)}{\left(y-1\right)y\left(x^2-1\right)^6}$

So It's is obvious that at the bottom there will be $(1-x^2)^{n+1}$, and there should be $(n+1)!$, but I can't see the pattern happening with $(x^2+1)$ at the top.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: $1/(1-x^2)$ is a linear combination of $1/(1-x)$ and $1/(1+x)$ both of which have calculable derivatives. You can do a similar thing with the y term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite the function as:

$$f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$$ where $$\begin{align}g(x)&=\frac1{1-x^2}=\frac12\left(\frac1{1+x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\h(y)&=\frac1{y-y^2}=\frac1y+\frac1{1-y}\end{align}$$

Then $$\frac{\partial^{n+m} f}{\partial x^n\partial y^m}=\frac{d^ng}{dx^n}\frac{d^mh}{dy^m}$$

All that is left is to compute $\frac{d^ng}{dx^n}$ and $\frac{d^mh}{dy^m}.$